# Dimension of a polynomial space over $O(n)$ with trace as the function

Tags: polynomials, trace, orthogonal-matrices

I have the following set:

$ \text{Pol}(O(n)) := \{ \rho_X | \rho_X(Y) := \text{tr}(X^T Y) \text{ where } X,Y \in O(n)\} $

So, for a function the $X$ is always fixed and we just have the $Y$ as input.

I want to determine the dimension of this polynomial space.

My first question is: do the $X$ play a role in the dimension? Because I have just ignored them and I am not sure whether that is right.

Since I didn't really know how to solve this, I just looked at $O(2)$ at first. We know:

$ O(2) = \Big\{ \begin{pmatrix}
 \cos a & -\sin a \\
 \sin a & \cos a \\
\end{pmatrix}, 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos a & \sin a \\
  \sin a & -\cos a \\
 \end{pmatrix} \mid a\in \mathbb{R}
\Big\} $

Let $X\in O(2)$ be arbitrary. We write:

$ X = \begin{pmatrix}
 x_{11} & x_{12} \\
 x_{12} & x_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

If we want to look at what $\rho_X(Y)$ is, we can distinguish between two cases for $Y$:

Case 1:$Y = \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos a & -\sin a \\
  \sin a & \cos a \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

$ \rho_X(Y) = tr \begin{pmatrix}
   x_{11}\cos a - x_{12} \sin a & \\
   & x_{21} \sin a + x_{22} \cos a \\
  \end{pmatrix} 
  = \cos a(x_{11} + x_{22}) + \sin a(-x_{12} + x_{21})$

Case 2: $Y = \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos a & \sin a \\
  \sin a & -\cos a \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

$ \rho_X(Y) = tr \begin{pmatrix}
   x_{11}\cos a + x_{12} \sin a & \\
   & x_{21} \sin a - x_{22} \cos a \\
  \end{pmatrix} 
  = \cos a(x_{11} - x_{22}) + \sin a(x_{12} + x_{21})$

Therefore, the only difference is that we have $\pm \sin a x_{12}$ and $\pm \cos a x_{22}$. But if we have been given a $Y$ that is of the form in the first case and we have a $Y'$ that is of the form in the second case, we can also represent $\rho_X(Y')$ with $\rho_{X'}(Y)$ for an $X'$ of the following form:

$ X' = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & -x_{12} \\
  x_{12} & -x_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix} $

Therefore, the polynomial space has dimension 1.

Would that be correct? If not, can somebody give me a hint?

Also, how would you go on now for $n\geq 2$ and determine the dimension of the polynomial space?

Thanks in advance for any reply!

--

Also: If you want to know where I have this exercise from: Godsil's book "Algebraic Combinatorics" (ch. 14, ex. 1)

Comment: What is a "polynomial space"? The traces of $X^TY$ are just real numbers?

Comment: @DietrichBurde A polynomial space is just what the set Pol($O(n)$) is called. As for the traces, yes, they are real.

Comment: As you defined ${\rm Pol}(O(n))$ it's a subset of $\Bbb R$. Based on its name and your question, I doubt that this is the space you wanted to ask about.

Comment: @Berci I meant it as a space that consists of functions

Comment: @Berci fixed my mistake

Comment: Much better, but it's still not a vector space because $O(n)$ is not one (e.g. your set doesn't contain the $0$ function). However, this can be corrected by running $X$ through the whole matrix space. Note that ${\rm tr}(X^TY)=\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}y_{ij}$ is just the regular inner product of the *flattened* matrices.